# Add event listeners to content of a custom tab

Tags: magento-1.9

I've tried many things but it always gives an error because the element isn't loaded yet.

**Jquery I've tried last:**

```
$('#draggable-holder').on('mousedown', '.dxy', function() {
  //do something
});
```

**How I render the content:**

```
$output = "";

$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($categoryId);

$output .= "<div id='draggable-holder'>";
foreach ($children as $category) {
    $output .= "<div class='dxy'>" . $category->getName() . "</div>";
    $output .= "<br />";
}
$output .= "</div>";

return $output;
```

So I'm tryig to add the `mousedown` event to the class `dxy`.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If the element isn't loaded yet, you should wait for the DOM to be ready before you bind the event listener

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#draggable-holder').on('mousedown', '.dxy', function() {
        //do something
    });
});
```

See jQuery documentation for more info:
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/